# React Native Arrow Syntax Explanation

Tags: javascript, syntax, arrow-functions

I am reviewing some code and was unable to find a breakdown of this arrow function syntax. Could someone help explain what the parameters `({ match, onOpen }: MatchListItemProps)` mean?

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

type MatchListItemProps = {
  match: User,
  onOpen: Function
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

const TestScreen = ({ match, onOpen }: MatchListItemProps) => {
  const { name, image, message } = match;
  return (....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone help explain what the parameters `({ match, onOpen }: MatchListItemProps)`mean?

This code is using typescript and destructuring. Let me get rid of both for a second, then add them back in. Here it is in pure javascript without destructuring:

```
const TestScreen = (props) => {
  let match = props.match;
  let onOpen = props.onOpen;
```

Now i'll add back in the typescript. A variable can be followed by a colon and then a type. This information is used to catch type errors at compile time.

```
const TestScreen = (props: MatchListItemProps) => {
  let match = props.match;
  let onOpen = props.onOpen;
```

And then adding in the destructuring. This is a shorthand to pluck values off an object and assign them to local variables:

```
const TestScreen = ({ match, onOpen }: MatchListItemProps) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the parameter is an object, you can deconstruct it inside the parameter.

For instance, take a look at this code

```
let person = {
   name: 'Felipe',
   age: '23'
}
```

You could take the values in this form

```
let name = person.name
let age = person.age
```

Or you could use a shortcut with destructuring assignment

```
let { name, age } = person
```

Finally, if the variable person inside a parameter, you can deconstruct it inside the very parameter

```
logPersonNameAndAge = ({ name, age }) => {
   console.log(name)
   console.log(age) 
}
```

So that you could call it passing the entire object

```
logPersonNameAndAge(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is TypeScript, not just JavaScript. `: MatchListItemProps` is a type annotation that's used by TypeScript, which is used to catch many common errors at compile time instead of at runtime. `({ match, onOpen }) => { ...` is a destructuring, which means the function takes an object, and brings into scope variables called `match` and `onOpen` containing whatever was in the object with those names. It's roughly equivalent to `obj => { let match = obj.match, onOpen = obj.onOpen; ...`. In turn, `const TestScreen = obj => { ...` is a lambda, which is roughly equivalent to `function TestScreen(obj) { ...`.